# Alert Visual Studio 2019 user when a specific configuration, e.g. Release, is specified

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

We are developing with Visual Studio 2019 and have halfway automated our release process -- currently it's done with several projects when built for Release configuration.  This is great and handy -- except if we forget to switch from Release configuration to another configuration when we continue our development.  And it's not just on build and debug that can cause problems if we leave it on Release.  If it's compiled for Release and configuration files are transformed with production connection strings, even actions like EF code first `Update-Database` can wreak havok.

What options are available in Visual Studio 2019 to alert a user when a specific configuration is active?   Extensions that turn the title bar to red, messages that pop up, etc -- anything is helpful.  Options that constantly warn of the configuration are most helpful.

Comment: I'm not aware of an extension that would do this, but I thought normally you would commit your changes to repo which then would trigger your build server to do what you seem to be doing manually with VS.

Comment: @Ray - the build server is ideal and we're working towards that.  Currently, this specific project is released manually and most of the automation is done via the Release configuration.  We need an interim solution that alerts us in VS so that we are aware we are in the Release configuration so we don't accidentally perform any release functions.